How do I use the "Maybe" data type in a math expression in Haskell?
MRE:
foo :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
foo _ [] = Nothing
foo n (m:ms)
    | -- some conditional statements that return Just <number here>
    | otherwise = 3 + (foo n ms)

Error:
Could not deduce (Num (Maybe Int)) arising from a use of ‘+’
      from the context: Eq a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   foo :: forall a. Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
        at functions.hs:22:1-40
In the expression: 3 + (foo n ms)


What works:
otherwise = fmap (+3) (foo n ms)

Is there any way to do this without fmap?
PS: The only constraint on a is Eq has to hold.

Why would you want to do this without fmap?  fmap is exactly the appropriate tool to use in this situation (assuming you want to preserve Nothing).

Why exactky do you want to get rid of the fmap. One of the problems of "weak type systems" is that because of implicit conversions, eventually the programmer loses track and therefore can no longer find where the bug occurs.

foo might really be two functions, a non-recursive function that returns Nothing on empty lists and Just x on non-empty lists, and a recursive helper that gets used on non-empty lists to compute the value of x for foo.

The problem is that 3 is Int but (foo n ms) is Maybe Int, and you cannot add them.
You can pattern match on the result of foo n ms explicitly if you don't want to fmap over Maybe Int.
otherwise = case foo n ms of
              Just x -> Just (3 + x)
              Nothing -> Nothing

It's also an option to use a Monad instance of Maybe, but it's kind of a redundant version of fmap (+3) (foo n ms).
otherwise = do
  x <- foo n ms
  pure (3 + x)

Yet another option would be lifting (+) to Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int with liftA2, but again, it's kind of another redundant version.
otherwise = liftA2 (+) (Just 3) (foo n ms)



Is there any way to do this without fmap?

You can use an accumulator, which is often more useful:
foo :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
foo n xs = go xs n 0 where
  go [] _ _ = Nothing
  go (m:ms) n a  = go ms n (a+3)

We thus start with a zero as third parameter, and sum up 3 each time the go (m:ms) n a fires.
This will avoid wrapping and unwrapping the value into a Just data constructor. At the end you thus use a Just a (or you add a to the result). So you thus do some additional bookkeeping with the recursion.

Any applicative can be given a Num instance; see also Ap. Some variations:
-- reuse the existing instance (problem: orphan instance)
deriving instance Num a => Num (Maybe a) via Ap Maybe a

-- implement the instance yourself (still an orphan)
instance Num a => Num (Maybe a) where
    fromInteger = pure . fromInteger
    (+) = liftA2 (+)
    abs = fmap abs
    -- ...etc.

-- use Ap in your function definition
foo :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Ap Maybe Int
foo _ [] = Ap Nothing
foo n (m:ms)
    | ...
    | otherwise = 3 + foo n ms

-- use Ap as an internal implementation detail
foo :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
foo n_ ms_ = getAp (foo' n_ ms_) where
    foo' _ [] = Ap Nothing
    foo' n (m:ms)
        | ...
        | otherwise = 3 + foo n ms

-- realize that all the fanciness is not worth avoiding one fmap
foo :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
foo _ [] = Nothing
foo n (m:ms)
    | ...
    | otherwise = (3+) <$> foo n ms

Be aware, though, that there's one law that most Num instances have that Ap Maybe a violates: Ap Nothing - Ap Nothing /= 0.

Worth commenting how it mentions that it's usually not a lawful instance...

@LouisWasserman I added a comment about Ap Maybe specifically, as I think that's the relevant one here. Thanks for the suggestion.

Consider whether you need arithmetic with Nothing, or if that's just a one-time issue for empty lists. That is, can you structure your code something like the following?
foo :: Num a => a -> [a] -> Maybe a
foo _ [] = Nothing
foo n ms = foo' n ms where
            foo' :: Num a => a -> [a] -> a
            foo' n [] = ...
            foo' n (m':ms') = 3 + foo' n ms'
      

